# Why The Pod Created By This Manifest Could be Deployed to GPU Worker without Specifying Nodeselector

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia, daemonset

I have created a pod by **kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/v1.9/nvidia-device-plugin.yml**

However, I notice that there is no nodeSelector. Then how could the pod be correctly deployed to target gpu machines?? Why it chose to skip the master machine? AFAK, the daemonset makes its pod to be deployed on every node, not just parts of the cluster without specifying any nodeselector.

Parts of the manifest:

```
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule
```

Events:

Cluster Information:
2 machines, one as master which has only one CPU and the other as worker which has both cpu and gpu in it.

kubernetes: 1.15

Comment: did it get deployed into all workers or only on GPU workers?

Comment: not sure. coz I only have two machines, one for master, the other for gpu worker. i don't know why k8s doesn't deploy it to the master. @ArghyaSadhu

Answer (score 0):

This is a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) which means it will get deployed into all worker nodes.

From the docs

> If you specify a .spec.template.spec.nodeSelector, then the DaemonSet
>   controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node selector.
>   Likewise if you specify a .spec.template.spec.affinity, then DaemonSet
>   controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node affinity.
>   If you do not specify either, then the DaemonSet controller will
>   create Pods on all nodes

Since Kubernetes 1.6, DaemonSets do not schedule on master nodes by default.If you add below toleration it will get deployed into all master nodes as well as all worker nodes.

```
tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
```

Comment: so do you mean that, without specifying node-role.kubernetes.io/master in the manifest, it will deploy all pods to workers by default? From the official page of daemonset, I didn't see any about this

Comment: yes..daemonset ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod

Comment: then why k8s would skip the master node if it's for all nodes? i dont quite understand

Comment: master has a label node-role.kubernetes.io/master: NoSchedule...so daemonset will not deploy a copy of the pod on master unless you add a toleration for that as I have mentioned.

Comment: I have edited my answer..hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Check the `taints` on all your nodes by running `kubectl describe node node-name | grep -i taint`. **Master node** by default has a `taint` which prevents regular `Pods` from being scheduled on that particular node. Note that master node is intended to serve exclusively for running **kubernetes control plane** components which live in `kube-system` namespace. Such solution ensures stability of **kubernetes cluster** and is totally justified. You may want to familiarize with [taints and tollerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

Answer (score 0):

Check the `taints` on all your nodes by running:

```
kubectl describe node <node-name> | grep -i taint
```

**Master node** by default has a `taint` which prevents regular `Pods` from being scheduled on that particular node. Note that master node is intended to serve exclusively for running **kubernetes control plane** components which live in `kube-system` namespace. Such solution ensures stability of **kubernetes cluster** and is totally justified. Generally deploying any additional production workload on **master node** is a bad idea. When it comes to non-production solutions such as **Minikube** when you have single node cluster it is totally acceptable. You may want to familiarize with [taints and tollerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) to understand better this concept.

Apart from adding tollerations to `Pod` specification you may consider [removing taints from your nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints) (described also [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#concepts)):

> **Removing a taint from a node** You can use `kubectl taint` to remove taints. You can remove taints by `key`, `key-value`, or `key-effect`.
>
> For example, the following command removes from node foo all the
>   taints with key dedicated:
>
> ```
> kubectl taint nodes foo dedicated-
> ```

**Important: taints are not labels!** as some comments may suggest. They may be related with labels but they are not labels themselves.

You can easily check it by running:

```
kubectl get node <tainted-node> -o yaml
```

and you'll see all currently applied taints in node's spec section:

```
spec:
  ...
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: key
    value: some-value
```

Typically on master node you have the following taint:

```
spec:
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

and among many other labels there is specific one related with this taint:

```
node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
```

**Answering your specific question that you posted in the title:**

> Why The Pod Created By This Manifest Could be Deployed to GPU Worker
>   without Specifying Nodeselector

I recommend you to read more about different mechanisms used by **kubernetes** for assigning `Pods` to `Nodes` in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) article and you'll see that [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) can be used if you want to guarantee that your `Pod` would be scheduled on node with specific labels. However absence of a `nodeSelector` doesn't prevent your `Pods` to be scheduled on such node. `Pods` can still be scheduled on every node that doesn't have any taints (preventing this way certain `Pods` that don't have specific toleration to be scheduled on it) or on any nodes that have some taints, however scheduled `Pod` can tolerate those taints.

In your case worker node is the only node that doesn't have on it taints, preventing `Pods` which don't tolerate this specific taint to be scheduled on it. Since worker node doesn't have any taints, the `Pod` is scheduled on it.

If you want to prevent any other `Pod` e.g. which don't require GPU from being scheduled on that specific node, you can create your own taint and only `Pods` that will have specific toleration, can be scheduled on such node.

I hope it cleared your doubts.